# Why won't Outlook 2016 connect to exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

2 PC's in the office will not connect to Exchange online / Office 365. Each time I try to setup the new exchange mail box it does its thinking thing, then crashes. Looking in the event viewer, it is logging an error message in German for each mailbox.

google translate for the error message says something along the lines of;

"Indexing your outlook data cannot be completed by the search. A continuation of indexing for  is not possible. 81404005 = error. Contact for continuation of the error Microsoft Services"

I have reset the password, deleted all windows credentials and recreated for the new one.

I have removed the KB article as described here. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-search-functionality-broken-after-latest/bafbd2aa-d27b-4259-9768-d361cb2cc481

And I have done the usually restart the PC, disable add-ins and so on, but no joy.

Anyone have any ideas what other steps I can take to fix this?

Comment: Are you the Exchange/office365 admin? If so, open a support ticket in the exchange admin panel.  I've done so twice in 4 years and received a phone call/callback in under 60 minutes both times.

Comment: Its not Exchange thats the issue, as most pcs are connected and working. Just 2 desktops and a laptop that crash whenever connecting to exchange to set up the account

Comment: Since outlook is also an office365 product I'd still give/follow that advice.  They have two things you don't, server logs that may or may not show failures and they have a huge database of past connection issues and how those were resolved.

Comment: In all fairness, I stand corrected, and it was something that MS themselves could fix, once I arranged a call back. Guess I shouldn't be so cynical! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

General troubleshooting steps:

1.If the same mailbox accounts can be setup successfully on other PCs, and no mailbox accounts can be setup successfully on these two PCs, then the issue is related to these two PCs.

In this situation:
1). Check the proxy settings on the PCs. Run *netsh winhttp show proxy* to check if you have any proxy setting. If there is, run *netsh winhttp reset proxy* to remove the proxy setting, then reboot the PC and try again.
2). Collect the [fiddler log](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) when the issue is reproduced, compare with the normal log when the profile can be successfully created.

2.If other mailbox accounts can be successfully setup on these two PCs, and the two mailbox cannot be setup successfully on any PCs, then the issue would be the mailbox account related.

In this situation, run [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Test](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/), see if there is any error. Also, try to login OWA with these two mailboxes. If they are two new mailboxes, and either of logging OWA or Outlook fails, try to recreate the accounts.

Comment: Outlook itsself crashes during the setting up of the users primary mailbox account, and they all have old smtp / pop accounts on them. My feeling is its outlook 16 thats the issue on these machines. May be time for a reinstall